# How to generate a PDF with eCharts content in NodeJS API

Tags: node.js, pdf-generation, echarts

I have a NodeJS API and I need to create an endpoint which creates a richly-featured dynamic PDF report and saves it to an S3 bucket.
I've been working with PDFKit (https://pdfkit.org/) and have most of what I need from there, but I've come up across a stumbling block because the latest design I've been given includes a donut chart generated with eCharts and I can't figure out how to include this using PDFKit. It needs to be generated dynamically for each call.
There is no visible HTML page which displays the report, this must all be achieved within the NodeJS API.

Are there any pre-existing solutions I'm overlooking that would make this possible?

NB I have some flexibility so it doesn't have to be specifically an eCharts solution, as long as I can include a stacked donut chart with labels.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is totally doable. I've put together an example that adds a chart to the PDFKit document.

```
const echarts = require("echarts");
const Canvas = require("canvas-prebuilt");
const { JSDOM } = require("jsdom");
const fs = require("fs");
const PDFDocument = require("pdfkit");
const SVGtoPDF = require("svg-to-pdfkit");

const option = {
  tooltip: {
    trigger: "item"
  },
  legend: {
    top: "5%",
    left: "center"
  },
  series: [
    {
      name: "Pie Chart",
      type: "pie",
      radius: ["40%", "70%"],
      avoidLabelOverlap: false,
      itemStyle: {
        borderRadius: 10,
        borderColor: "#fff",
        borderWidth: 2
      },
      label: {
        show: false,
        position: "center"
      },
      emphasis: {
        label: {
          show: true,
          fontSize: "40",
          fontWeight: "bold"
        }
      },
      labelLine: {
        show: false
      },
      data: [
        { value: 1048, name: "A" },
        { value: 735, name: "B" },
        { value: 580, name: "C" },
        { value: 484, name: "D" },
        { value: 300, name: "E" }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

const getChartSVG = (option) => {
  echarts.setCanvasCreator(() => {
    return Canvas.createCanvas(100, 100);
  });

  const { window } = new JSDOM();
  global.window = window;
  global.navigator = window.navigator;
  global.document = window.document;

  const root = document.createElement("div");
  root.style.cssText = "width: 500px; height: 500px;";

  const chart = echarts.init(root, null, {
    renderer: "svg"
  });

  chart.setOption(option);

  const chartSvg = root.querySelector("svg").outerHTML;
  chart.dispose();

  return chartSvg;
};

const makePDF = (svg) => {
  const doc = new PDFDocument();
  const stream = fs.createWriteStream("file.pdf");

  SVGtoPDF(doc, svg, 0, 0);

  stream.on("finish", function() {
    console.log("Done");
  });

  doc.pipe(stream);
  doc.end();
};

const run = () => {
  const svg = getChartSVG(option);
  makePDF(svg);
};

run();
```

Here `svg-to-pdfkit` library plays an important role of adding the svg content to the pdf document or else it would have been quite difficult to implement this.

Find the code repository here: https://github.com/muraliprajapati/echarts-node-pdf

Comment: You're a total legend! Thanks so much!

Comment: Credits to these open source libraries. I just integrated them.

Comment: Thanks, but I have 1 question: What is the purpose of Canvas here if you are using svg renderer?

This part:
```
echarts.setCanvasCreator(() => {
    return Canvas.createCanvas(100, 100);
});
```

Comment: Even though this is svg rendering, I guess that Canvas is still used by echarts for purposes of measuring text before rendering.

Answer (score 0):

From echart 5.3.0 is easier to generate svg on server side. You can now remove jsdom dependency.

Here is an example:

```
const echarts = require('echarts');

// In SSR mode the first container parameter is not required
const chart = echarts.init(null, null, {
    renderer: 'svg', // must use SVG rendering mode
    ssr: true, // enable SSR
    width: 400, // need to specify height and width
    height: 300
});

// use setOption as normal
chart.setOption({
   //...
});

// Output a string
const svgStr = chart.renderToSVGString();
```

Or, you can also use an alternative service [Carbone](https://carbone.io/documentation.html#echarts-5-charts) to generate pdf including echarts.